# DNS servers and load balancing

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

I'm wondering if a simple DNS server could offer, even a limited amount, of load balancing capability.

I have a couple of servers and I've been told that multiple IPAddresses can be associated with one domain.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can provide very limited load balancing using a technique called round-robin DNS.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS.

Comment: +1 Accurate description, "very limited load balancing"